# How can I list all function keys?

Tags: emacs-internals

Seems that `src/keyboard.c` file contains C string arrays for `(info "(elisp) Function Keys")`.

Is there a way to get that list in Elisp?

I discovered that such symbols have special properties:

```
(symbol-plist 'backspace)
==> (event-symbol-element-mask (backspace 0) event-symbol-elements (backspace) ascii-character 127 event-kind function-key modifier-cache ((8388608 . s-backspace) (201326592 . C-M-backspace) (134217728 . M-backspace) (67108864 . C-backspace) (0 . backspace) (100663296 . C-S-backspace)))
```

But some of them:

```
(symbol-plist 'XF86AudioPlay)
```

are empty until I press corresponding key.

For all pressed keys it is:

```
(mapatoms (lambda (ob) (when (eq (get ob 'event-kind) 'function-key)
                    (message "%s" ob)))
            obarray)
```

You ask why? Because I dig in Emacs internals...

Comment: I'm unsure what the actual question is. What is about your `mapatoms` code that doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: `symbol-plist` is empty until I press corresponding key. I try to get full list even kays that not in my keyboard...

Comment: My guess is that Emacs just discovers these symbols when you press a key and the X server sends a corresponding event.